# c# datetime hour minute validation

Tags: c#, regex

```
11/11/2011 15:04  VALID ANYTHING OUTSIDE OF THIS IS FORMAT INVALID
11/11/11 12:04    INVALID
11/11/2011 15:0   INVALID
```

I am thinking on min characters to be 16 
what else can I do. Other solutions out there?

Comment: Out of interest, does it HAVE to be Regex? Otherwise, [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) might be an option.

Comment: thanks i will explore that. No it can be anything as long as is elegant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at TryParseExact and see if the date can be parsed, this is adapted from [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-tryparseexact).

```
string dateString = "11/11/2011 15:04"; // <-- Valid
string format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
  Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
}
```

The above uses dd and MM which means that it expects a two digit day and month. If you just want one digit just use the singular d / M.

Comment: try parse exact is nice because I can return false on the catch for validation

Answer (score 3):

I would use:

```
DateTime parsedValue = DateTime.ParseExact(stringOfDateTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
```

(although I don't know if your month or days come first since you chose 11 for both)

Comment: Just keep in mind that this will throw a ParseException on a failure that will need to be handled. If an exception is not what you want then consider using the TryParseExact alternative which returns a boolean indicating success.